# Программирование конца игры в игре Конвея “Жизнь”

Tags: javascript

Пишу вариацию игры "*Жизнь*" (*Conway's Game of Life*).  Добрался до того, что игре  стоит добавить логический конец.
Логика самой игры представлена двумерным массивом который делит поле на аккуратные квадратики. Если в ячейке "1", клетку закрашиваем (*это живая клетка*), если ноль - клетка мертвая, цвета нет.

Мне видится для окончания игры два условия:

- Или на поле не осталось не одной живой клетки.
- Или за итерацию цикла не было изменений по количеству живых клеток.

Но тут есть подводный камень: игра порождает движущиеся фигуры, которые через какое-то время могу врезаться в неподвижную фигуру и опять начнется деление клеток.

Как можно решить данную задачу?

https://jsfiddle.net/pridan/g0c7okmL/2/

```
"use strict";

(function () {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var size = 500;
  var meshSize = size / 10;
  canvas.width = size;
  canvas.height = size;
  var speed = 100;
  var arr = [];
  var count = 0;
  var countPopulation = 0;
  var countLive = 0;
  var timer = void 0;

  init();

  function init() {
    initButtons();
    initGameFiaeld();
  }

  /**
   * Clear field call
   */
  function clear() {
    stop();
    clearCanvas();
    resetGenerations();
    resetGameField();
    canvasBoard();
  }

  /**
   * Board playing field
   */
  var canvasBoard = function canvasBoard() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, size, size);
  };
  canvasBoard();

  /**
   * Field clearing function
   */
  function clearCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);
  }

  function drawPoint() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {

        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
          countPopulation += 1;
          ctx.fillRect(j * 10, i * 10, 10, 10);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Draw points
   */
  function initGameFiaeld() {
    canvas.addEventListener('click', clickPosition);
    function clickPosition(event) {
      var x = event.offsetX;
      var y = event.offsetY;
      x = Math.floor(x / 10);
      y = Math.floor(y / 10);

      for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
          if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
            arr[y][x] = 1;
          }
        }
      }
      arr[y][x] = 1;
      drawPoint();
      canvasBoard();
    }

    goLife();

    /**
     *  Blank field
     */
    function goLife() {
      for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
        arr[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
          arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   *  Clear field clear function
   */
  function resetGameField() {
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
          arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    drawPoint();
  }

  /**
   * Initialize Buttons
   */
  function initButtons() {
    var startBtn = document.getElementById('start-evolution');
    var stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop-evolution');
    var clearBtn = document.getElementById('clear');
    startBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
      start();
      startBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    });
    stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
      stop();
      startBtn.removeAttribute('disabled', true);
    });
    clearBtn.addEventListener('click', clear);
  }

  /**
   *  Check the existence conditions of points
   */

  function startLife() {
    var arr2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      arr2[i] = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
        var neighbors = 0;
        if (arr[checkMinus(i) - 1][j] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[i][checkPlus(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkPlus(i) + 1][j] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[i][checkMinus(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkMinus(i) - 1][checkPlus(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkPlus(i) + 1][checkPlus(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkPlus(i) + 1][checkMinus(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkMinus(i) - 1][checkMinus(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;

        if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
          arr2[i][j] = neighbors == 3 ? 1 : 0;
        } else {
          arr2[i][j] = neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3 ? 1 : 0;
        }
        getArrHash();
      }
    }

    drawPoint();
    canvasBoard();
    count++;
    timer = setTimeout(startLife, speed);
    updateGenerations();
    updatePopulation(innerUpdatePopulation);
  }

  function getArrHash() {
    var arrHash = arr2.toString();
    var currentHash = arr.toString();
    if (arrHash == currentHash) {
      gameOver();
    }
    arr = arr2;
  }

  /**
   *  Counting cell for living cells
   */
  function updatePopulation(param) {
    countPopulation = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
          countPopulation += 1;
        }
      }
    }
    param();
  }

  function innerUpdatePopulation() {
    var populationDiv = document.getElementById('cell-life');
    populationDiv.innerHTML = countPopulation;
  }

  /**
   * Cycle counter (generation)
   */
  function updateGenerations() {
    var generationDiv = document.getElementById('count');
    generationDiv.innerHTML = count;
  }

  /**
   * game over
   */
  function gameOver() {
    console.log('game over');
  }

  /**
   * Resetting cycles (generations)
   */
  function resetGenerations() {
    count = 0;
    updateGenerations();
  }

  /**
   * Check borders
   */
  function checkMinus(i) {
    if (i == 0) return meshSize;else return i;
  }

  /**
   * Check borders
   */
  function checkPlus(i) {
    if (i == meshSize - 1) return -1;else return i;
  }

  function start() {
    startLife();
  }

  function stop() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
})();

<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>

<p>Циклы</p><span id="count">0</span>
<p>Популяция</p>
<div id="cell-life">0</div>
<button id="start-evolution">Start</button>

<button id="stop-evolution">Stop</button>

<button id="next-generation" hidden>Next</button>

<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Comment: `Игра порождает движущиеся фигуры. Которые через какое-то время могу врезаться в неподвижную фигуру и начнётся опять деление клеток. Как можно решить данную задачу?`. Не понимаю, Вам нужно убрать движущиеся фигуры? Это бессмысленно, движущиеся фигуры - часть игры.

Comment: Наверно не совсем точно сформулировал вопрос. Мне нужно не убрать фигуру.  Я хочу реализовать функцию окончания игры. Но из за движущихся фигур я не могу сравнить  предведущую интерацию цикла с текущей чтоб выяснить что изменений не было. И окончить игру

Comment: `Или за итерацию цикла не было изменений по количеству живых клеток.`. Просто посчитайте количество живых клеток в текущем и предыдущем поколениях и сравните их.

Comment: Смысл «жизни» как раз в её бесконечности (кроме тривиального — все умерли).

Comment: +1, у игры жизнь конец не предусмотрен. Предусмотрены тривиальные состояния..

Comment: @AlexeyTen, игра прекращается и тогда, когда образуется периодическая конфигурация.

Comment: http://conwaylife.com/wiki/OTCA_metapixel долго будете ждать период (и это ещё не самый большой)

Comment: @AlexeyTen случайно такая фигура врядли образуется. Обычно из периодических какие-нибудь мигалки и планеры остаются.

Comment: Спасибо за участие.  Я попрообовал использовать совет  Eanmos  и сравнить количество живых клеток в текущим и предведущим поколении. Но у мяня не вышло. Подскажите как это сделать. Если можно с примером

Comment: @pridan, сравнение полных слепков состояний дал в вашем уже закрытом вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/680987/221753 .

Comment: @br3t  Пробовал несколько вариантов как прикрутить твой пример к своему коду но так  не вышло.:(   Глянь пожалуйста что не так.  Буду благодарен.

Comment: Конец вообще-то не предусмотрен.