# Сравнение двумерно массива в цикле с предыдущий итерацией

Tags: javascript

Пишу вариацию игры "Жизнь" (Conway's Game of Life). 
Логика самой игры представлена двумерным массивом который делит поле на аккуратные квадратики. Если в ячейке "1", клетку закрашиваем (это живая клетка), если ноль - клетка мертвая, цвета нет.

Сам вопрос
Хочу выводить сообщение "игра окончена" когда в новой итерации  цикла количество живых клеток не изменилось по отношению к предыдущей. Для этого я так понимаю мне нужно сравнить текущие значение массивов с значением в предыдущей итерацией. То-есть проверить количество живых ячеек с "1" cейчас  с количеством ячеек с "1"  в предыдущей итерации. Но у меня не выходи это сделать. Подскажите как это делается. можно с примером. Спасибо.

https://jsfiddle.net/pridan/g0c7okmL/

```js
(function() {
  // initialParams();
  // function initialParams() {
  //
  //
  // }
  // var enterSize = prompt("Введите размер поля?", "");
  // var enterSpeed = prompt("Введите скорость?", "");

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var size = 500;
  var meshSize = size / 10;
  canvas.width = size;
  canvas.height = size;
  var speed = 100;

  var arr = [];
  var count = 0;
  var countPopulation = 0;
  var countLive = 0;
  var timer;

  init();

  function init() {
    initButtons();
    initGameFiaeld();
  }

  //вызов очистки поля
  function clear() {
    stop();
    clearCanvas();
    resetGenerations();
    resetGameField();
    canvasBoard();
  }

  //Рамка игрового поля
  var canvasBoard = function() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, size, size);
  };
  canvasBoard();
  //Рамка игрового поля функция очистки поля
  function clearCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);
  }

  function drawPoint() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
          countPopulation += 1;
          ctx.fillRect(j * 10, i * 10, 10, 10);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //Рисуем точки
  function initGameFiaeld() {
    canvas.addEventListener('click', clickPosition);

    function clickPosition(event) {
      var x = event.offsetX;
      var y = event.offsetY;
      x = Math.floor(x / 10);
      y = Math.floor(y / 10);

      for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
          if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
            arr[y][x] = 1;
          }
        }
      }
      arr[y][x] = 1;
      drawPoint();
      canvasBoard();
    }

    //Размечаю поле
    var goLIfe = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
        arr[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
          arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }();
  }

  //Функция сброса очистки поля
  function resetGameField() {
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
          arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    drawPoint();

  }

  //Иницилизация кнопок
  function initButtons() {
    var startBtn = document.getElementById('start-evolution');
    var stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop-evolution');
    var clearBtn = document.getElementById('clear');

    startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

      start();
      startBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    });

    stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

      stop();
      startBtn.removeAttribute('disabled', true);
    });
    clearBtn.addEventListener('click', clear);
  }

  //Проверка условий существования точек
  function startLife() {
    var arr2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      arr2[i] = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
        var neighbors = 0;
        if (arr[checkMinus(i) - 1][j] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[i][checkPlus(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkPlus(i) + 1][j] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[i][checkMinus(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkMinus(i) - 1][checkPlus(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkPlus(i) + 1][checkPlus(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkPlus(i) + 1][checkMinus(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkMinus(i) - 1][checkMinus(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;

        if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
          arr2[i][j] = neighbors == 3 ? 1 : 0;
        } else {
          arr2[i][j] = neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3 ? 1 : 0;
        }
      }
    }
    arr = arr2;

    drawPoint();
    canvasBoard();
    count++;
    timer = setTimeout(startLife, speed);
    updateGenerations();
    updatePopulation(innerUpdatePopulation);
  }


  //Cчётчик для подсчёта живых клеток
  function updatePopulation(param) {
    countPopulation = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
          console.log(arr);
          countPopulation += 1;
        }
      }
    }
    param();

  }

  function innerUpdatePopulation() {
    var populationDiv = document.getElementById('cell-life');
    populationDiv.innerHTML = countPopulation;
  }

  //Счетчик циклов(поколений)
  function updateGenerations() {
    var generationDiv = document.getElementById('count');
    generationDiv.innerHTML = count;
  }

  //Конец игры
  function gameOver() {

  }


  //Сброс циклов(поколений)
  function resetGenerations() {
    count = 0;
    updateGenerations();
  }

  //Проверка границ
  function checkMinus(i) {
    if (i == 0) return meshSize;
    else return i;
  }

  //Проверка границ
  function checkPlus(i) {
    if (i == meshSize - 1) return -1;
    else return i;
  }

  function start() {
    startLife();
  }

  function stop() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }

})();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>

<p>Циклы</p><span id="count">0</span>
<p>Популяция</p>
<div id="cell-life">0</div>
<button id="start-evolution">Start</button>

<button id="stop-evolution">Stop</button>

<button id="next-generation" hidden>Next</button>

<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На текущей итерации преобразуете массив в строку, сохраняете, на следующей опять получаете строку и сравниваете со строкой, полученной на предыдущей итерации.

```
var arrHash = "";

function getArrHash() {
  var currentHash = arr.toString();
  if(arrHash == currentHash) {
    gameOver();
  }
  arrHash = currentHash;
}
```

Если вам нужно сохранять только количество, тогда так:

```
var arrHash = 0;

function getArrHash() {
  var currentHash = arr.toString().split(',').reduce(function(sum, v) {
    return +v + sum
  }, 0);
  if (arrHash == currentHash) {
    gameOver();
  }
  arrHash = currentHash;
}
```

Comment: Не могу понять как выходит сравнить текущую и предведущую итерацию. Проходит итерация цилка.  Текущие значение массива преобразуеться  в string. Выходит что я постоянно перезаписываю текущую  версию и ту что сравниваю...

Comment: Да, с каждой итерацией сохраняется состояние, которое для следующей итерации будет состоянием предыдущей итерации.